# How to use image picker in iPad?

Tags: ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I know how to use image picker in iPhone , although know need to use new class UIPopoverController in iPad, but still can not figure out one way to use image pickr in iPad, any one has the same problem ? thanks

Answer (score 3):

UIImagePickerController is just a view controller. If you know how to use a UIPopoverController to present a view controller, then it's just the same way.

```
UIImagePickerController* imagePicker = ...
UIPopoverController* popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                                 initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
[imagePicker release];
[popover presentPopoverFromRect:...];
```