# camera code crash on iPad2

Tags: iphone, ipad, crash, uiimagepickercontroller, ipad-2

I am using camera in my iPhone app and when i open this app in my iPad2 it crashes when i click that camera button..

Here is my code for using camera

```
-(void) loadCamera{



UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    [imagePickerController setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    [imagePickerController setDelegate:self];


    [imagePickerController setAllowsEditing:YES];
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:NO];
    [imagePickerController release];

}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo 
{

//      UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
//      [alert show];
//      [alert release];

        [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    //      // Access the uncropped image from info dictionary
        //  UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
            self.cameraimage.image=image;
            self.tinyImage.image=image;

        // Make the needed component visible
            self.cameraimage.hidden=NO;
            self.RemoveImage.hidden=NO;
            self.RetakePicture.hidden=NO;
            self.addphoto.hidden=YES;

            // Save image
            [constants saveImage:image withName:self.largeImageName];
            [constants saveImage:image withName:self.tinyImageName];
}
```

This code works good on iPhone but on iPad2 it crashed.

My app is not for iPad .....but running it by using 2x in iPad

please help.

Comment: check for source type either camera or library and then proceed always

Comment: and also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210052/how-to-use-image-picker-in-ipad

Answer (score 0):

You should always first check the isSourceTypeAvailable: first

```
UIImagePickerControllerSourceType sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:sourceType])
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.sourceType = sourceType;
    picker.delegate = self;
    if(sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera)
        [picker takePicture];
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
}
```